# populate data from sqlite to action bar overflow

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, android-actionbar

[Action Bar Overflow (No. 4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkDGm.png)

Hi, I'm trying to add a list of data to the Action Bar Overflow (No. 4).
I know how to add the fixed items from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275540/define-action-bar-overflow-items), but not sure how to get it from sqlite table and display the list under the Action Overflow Menu.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580701/5993410)

Comment: exactly what I want, thanks a lot.